# In a forked child process, process.exit() is executed before the await functions are complete

Tags: node.js

I call process.exit() at the end of an event handler in a forked child process, after some async functions that I call with await.

```
process.on('message', async (message) => {
    try {
      await setup(message);
      await run(message);
    } catch (err) {
    }
    process.exit();
});
```

My expectation is the async functions to be completed before process.exit() is executed, but it looks like the process.exit() is called before the async functions are complete. If I remove the process.exit(), the child process completes the async functions but then it doesn't exit which is not desirable.

Comment: When I see questions like "Why isn't my code behaving the way I expected it to?", and then you have a try/catch that swallows all exceptions silently, it's a bit hard to take the question seriously. Can you please remove the try/catch block or at the very least log exceptions so that you can rule out that it doesn't just crash?

Comment: You sure, the functions are correctly awaiting their results? Or, they may return a promise, but there may be another, long-running process inside, which is not "awaited" by that promise. Another possibility is, that one of the functions is throwing an exception, you are silently ignoring.

Comment: Karlsen, I have tried the code without try/catch with the same issue. I thought that I should put a try/catch to make sure that child process executes exit() to prevent it from lingering around in case of crash but then I learnt that the child process exits automatically in case of crash so I shouldn't need the try/catch. But it doesn't change the problem as I have tested without the try/catch too.

Comment: derpirscher, the observation is that when I remove the process.exit(), the async functions get completed so that tells me that the functions are OK. And these functions have been working for a long time until I introduced the child processes to make them run in a more concurrent fashion

Comment: derpirscher, I agree that there is something in my functions that causes this but I can't see what kind of issue might cause this behavior.

Comment: I'm so sorry everyone. It turned out that I was overlooking an underlying forEach in my newly introduced code inside the child process that I changed to await asyncForEach function that I had implemented before and that resolved the issue